# How to decode HTML content from database in ASP.Net Page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I retrieved HTML content from my Db in ASP.net page but all tags are showed in my page as follow

```
<p>fdvdfb <strong>fbgdfbd</strong> <em>fbfgbggggggggggggggggggggg</em></p>
<p>iuiononknonbn</p>
<p>khbkinniln</p>
```

But it is not fair! How can I remove these tags? And show my text as they inserted?

My code is:

```
string query = "SELECT TOP 1[Text] FROM [News] ORDER BY Id DESC";
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycs"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtHTMLContent.Text = sdr["Text"].ToString();
            }
            sdr.Close();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

And

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHTMLContent" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Razor, you can do this:

```
@Html.Raw(yourvariable)
```

Otherwise in ASP.NET you can try:

```
element.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlDecode(yourText);
```

Comment: in which part of my code I can use it ?

Comment: When you set the value of txtHTMLContent

Answer (score 0):

Bind your data on `.aspx` to a dataSource. You can do it declaratively.

```
<asp:SomeKindOfRepeater runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlSourceName">
    <SomeKindOftemTemplate>
       <p>fdvdfb <strong>fbgdfbd</strong> <em><%#Eval("something")%></em></p>
       ...and so on
    </SomeKindOftemTemplate>
</asp:SomeKindOfRepeater>
<asp:SomeDataSource ID="sqlSourceName" runat="server" ...>
...
</asp:SomeDataSource>
```

Comment: text is dynamic and it may change , is there any other way ?

Comment: If your text changes in the DB then this is the approach. Else... no information, no ideas.

Answer (score -1):

I had tried a line of code and it is worked for me.

```
 string str = @"<p>fdvdfb <strong>fbgdfbd</strong> <em>fbfgbggggggggggggggggggggg</em></p>
             <p>iuiononknonbn</p>
             <p>khbkinniln</p>";

 txtHTMLContent.Text = Regex.Replace(str, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

OutPut :

First i got output on Label and second on TextBox.

[image]